# Не загружается изображение после редиректа

Tags: java, android, redirect, android-asynctask, https

Есть код он нормально загружает фотки в приложении.

```
class Pictureyy extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    ImageView bmImage;
    // конструктор
    private Pictureyy(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    // private final String Tag = "frag";
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
    //загружаем картинку в фоне
        try {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(urldisplay)
                .openStream());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Request exception",
                "Exception: " + e.getMessage()); // Oops
        }

        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    //      dialog.dismiss();
    // показываем если она есть
        if (result!=null)
        {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    // image.post(true);

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        /*
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        dialog.setMessage("Загрузка...");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.show();
        */
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
}

//вызов асинк таска передаем данные конструктору, и параметр асинк таску
new Pictureyy((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1))
.execute("http://vtormet.ru/android/timetable/"+Kurs+"/"+Group+"/"
    + positionnew + ".png");
```

Но когда я делаю на хостинге перенаправление с http на https версию сайта, фотки не загружаются. 
С чем это может быть связано?
Redirect делаю в virtualhost
В браузере по той же ссылке фото загружается.
Вот строчки логов на сервере, видно что сервер дает ответ 301, но размер маловат для фото 592 байта:
[image: логи сервера]

Comment: У вас на сервере самоподписанный сертификат?

Comment: Нет, выданный .

Comment: @androidDrill советую для загрузки изображений использовать Picasso или Universal Image Loader

Comment: Непонятно, о чём речь - судя по логам, вы пытаетесь просматривать изборажения - а пишите, что загружаете. Что происходит с изображениями-то, download или upload (с сервера на клиент они передаются или с клиента на сервер)?